# How to make unique view count in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: laravel-4

I'm developing this site and I want to add view count to it. I want to increment view count +1 when you visit post/{id}. But I don't really know where to start with it.

I've prepared my database to the point where I just need to create cookie or something.

Comment: You'll need to define in more details what you mean by "unique view". Single view from given IP? from given authorized user? from given computer? from...?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In this example, you increment the count each time you visit post/{id}.

```
// Table
Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    ...
    $table->integer('count');
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
});



public function show($id) 
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    Post::update([
        'count' => $post->count + 1
    ]);

    //OR  DB::table('posts')
    //     ->where('id', $id)
    //     ->update(['count' => $post->count + 1]);

    return View::make('posts', compact('post'));
}
```